# Test.isrunningTest and (?:) meaning?

Tags: apex, unit-test, customsetting

What does the below line of code mean?

```
String ProcessStr =(!test.isRunningTest())? Customsetting__c.getInstance('Process').value__c:'0';
```

Comment: Note: this is Bad Code. If you need the value of a custom setting in a unit test, the custom setting should be created as part of the test setup.

Comment: Never use `Test.isRunningTest` unless you can find no alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm?search_text=ternary) is quite clear on what this specific method does, and the name is essentially self documenting:

> - **isRunningTest()**
>   Returns true if the currently executing code was called by code contained in a test method, false otherwise. Use this method if you need to run different code depending on whether it was being called from a test.

As for ternary syntax (`?:`), you can see that documented in the `Apex Developer Guide` under [`Expression Operators`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm?search_text=ternary):

> Operator
> ? :
>
> Syntax
> x ? y : z
>
> Description
> Ternary operator (Right associative). This operator acts as a short-hand for if-then-else statements. If x, a Boolean, is true, y is the result. Otherwise z is the result. Note that x cannot be null.

So the translation of your code to plain English is essentially:

*If this code is running in a live transaction (not a test), then get the value from a custom setting. Otherwise, use a value of `'0'`.*